# Changing WordPress' Template Hierarchy

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there an easy way to change the WP default template hierarchy?

For instance;

Say I want to change my theme directory structure so that it completely changes from the Template Hierarchy suggested here based upon conditionals:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

if I wanted to make sure that for all page types (`is_single()` `is_home()` etc) it always opens one template file which then instigates my own pattern to provide the output?

Thanks very much!

Comment: don't make duplicate questions: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63614/changing-the-template-hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:
Easy to read and works well

single.php:

```
<?php include_once('template-you-want.php');
```

home.php:

```
<?php include_once('template-you-want.php');
```

If you don't want to have these two files at all do it in index.php:

```
<?php
// at the very top
if (is_single()){
    include_once('template-you-want.php');
    die(); // don't continue
}

if (is_home()){
    include_once('template-you-want.php');
    die(); // don't continue
}
```